# Why are images not appearing on my iphone for Alert emails?

Tags: 2013, email, alert, mobile

We created a custom list with a rich text field.  Images are added to this text field whenever the user is entering data.  If I subscribe to alerts, the image is embedded in the alert that I receive via Microsoft Outlook on my desktop computer.  However, whenever I pull up the alert on my iPhone, the image is not appearing.

How do I make the images appear within the iPhone email messages?

Comment: Does your site allow anonymous users for this custom list?

Comment: no, the site does not allow anonymous users